# Having issues allocating a new struct

Tags: c, struct, singly-linked-list

I've read half a dozen answers with regards to this here and am relatively loathe to ask such a question, but I'm attempting to create a linked list using a struct in C, and was having some issues in passing pointers to the linked list. I think it's mostly sorted, but honestly am having acute issues trying to get the linked list working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct cell
{
        int value;
        struct cell *next;
} cell;

int inputplace = 0;

cell * createlist()
{
        cell curElement = (cell *)  malloc(sizeof(cell));
        cell *head = &curElement;
        cell *curEl = &curElement;
        curEl->value = 900;
        FILE *fp;
        char *mode = "r";
        fp = fopen("input",mode);

        if(fp==NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file 'input'");
                exit(1);
        }

        int val;
        int tempplace = 0;
        while(tempplace < inputplace)
        {
                if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &val) != EOF)
                {
                        tempplace++;
                        printf("%d", &val);
                }
                else
                        break;
        } 

        while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &val)!=EOF)
        {
                inputplace++;
                printf("%d\n", curEl);
                if(val < 0)
                {
                        curEl->value = -1;
                        curEl->next = -1;
                        break;
                }
                printf("%d\n", val);
                curEl->value = val;
                curEl->next = malloc(sizeof(struct cell));
                curEl= curEl->next;
        }
        return head;
}
cell* reverse(cell* p)
{
        cell * prev = -1;
        cell * current = p;
        cell * next;
        while(current->value != -1)
        {
                next = current->next;
                current->next = prev;
                prev = current;
                current = next;
        }
        return prev;
}
cell* append(cell* p, cell* q)
{
        cell * current = p;
        cell * r = p;
        while(1)
        {
                if(current->value == -1)
                {
                        current->value = q->value;
                        current->next = q->next;
                }
        }
        return r;
}
int last(cell *p)
{
        cell q = *p;
        int last = -1;
        while(1)
        {
                if(q.value == -1)
                {
                        return last;
                }
                else
                {
                        last = q.value;
                        q = *q.next;
                }
        }
}
cell * delete(int n, cell *p)
{
        cell * head = p;
        cell * prev = -1;
        cell * current = p;
        if(current-> value == n)
        {
                return current->next;
        }
        else
        {
                while(current->value != -1)
                {
                        if(current->value==n)
                        {
                                prev->next = current->next;
                                break;
                        }
                        prev = current;
                        current = current->next;
                }
        }
        return head;
}
int member(int n, cell *p)
{
        cell q = *p;
        while(1)
        {
                if(q.value == n)
                {
                        return 1;
                }
                if(q.value == -1)
                {
                        return 0;
                }
                q = *q.next;
        }
}

int display(cell *p)
{
        printf(" %c", '[');
        cell q = *p;
        while(1)
        {
                if(q.value == -1)
                {
                        printf("%c ",']');
                        return 1;
                }
                if(q.next != p->next)
                        printf("%c ",',');
                printf("%d", q.value);
                q = *q.next;
        }
        printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
        cell *head = createlist();
        cell *headk = createlist();
        cell *head3 = delete(5, head);
        printf("%d, %d\n", head->value, head->next->value);
        printf("Last head: %d\n", last(head));
        display(headk);
        display(head);
        display(head3);
        cell *head4 = delete(6, head);
        display(head4);
        cell *head5 = delete(7, head);
        display(head5);
        printf("Member2 6, head: %d\n", member(6,head));
        printf("Member2 3, head: %d\n", member(3, head));

        cell *head2 = reverse(head);
        //print(head2);
        printf("%d, %d\n", head2->value, head2->next->value);
}
```

So the input file contains numerical data with a negative one terminating the list:

Example input I'm using:

```
5
6
7
-1
1
2
3
-1
```

The issue I'm having is the second list is apparently overriding the first or some such, and my pointer-fu is weak, what do I need to do to successfully allocate the new structs?

Charles B.

Comment: First of all, you can't assign integer to a pointer. Use NULL instead of -1.

Comment: ähm, what is `cell curElement = (cell *)  malloc(sizeof(cell));` supposed to do? also, you should use `NULL` (0) for invalid pointers, not "-1"; i guess you should read a lot about pointer arithmetic...

Comment: I've tried to compile the code. Lots of errors.

Comment: i was just going to ask: which compiler are you using? that code can never compile...

Comment: gcc 4.8.3 20140911, and it's compiling with out complaint. Which the fact that this shouldn't be compiling explains a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return a pointer to a local variable, and local variables goes out of scope once the function returns and that leaves you with a stray pointer. Using that stray pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The problem starts with the declaration of `curElement`, and the compiler should really have screamed at you for that:

```
cell curElement = (cell *)  malloc(sizeof(cell));
```

Here you declare `curElement` to be an actual structure, and not a pointer to the structure.

---

There's also the problem that you don't really have an *end* to the list. You allocate the `next` pointer of the last node you add, regardless if there's going to be a next node or not, and you don't initialize that node so the memory you allocate will be uninitialized, and trying to access it will lead to yet another undefined behavior.

---

I suggest something like the following abbreviated code:

```
cell *head = NULL;
cell *tail = NULL;

...

while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &val) == 1)
{
    ...
    cell *current = malloc(sizeof(*current));
    current->val = val;
    current->next = NULL;  // Very important!

    // Check if this is the first node in the list
    if (head == NULL)
        head = tail = current;
    else
    {
        // List is not empty, append node to end of list
        tail->next = current;
        tail = current;
    }
}
```

Beside the change in how the list is handled and added to, there are also two other changes: The first is that the return value from the `fscanf` function is compared against `1`, because `fscanf` (and family) will return the number of successfully parsed items, and this allows you to find format errors in the input file.

The second change is to not cast the return of `malloc`. In C you should never cast from or to `void *`, cast like that can hide subtle bugs.

Comment: Thank you, your guidance has very much so gotten me off on the right track. Thank you, sir.